# How do I include a superscript to texts on a plot on R?

Tags: r, plot, legend, superscript

I need it to look like this:

R^2 = some values

And I've tried the code below but it wouldn't work, it came out as "R (expression (^2)) = some values" instead:

```
text (25, 200, paste ("R (expression (^2)) =", round (rsquarelm2, 2)))
```

Comment: I found this with a Google search.  Maybe you can modify it: `text(-pi/2, 0, expression(hat(alpha) == (X^t * X)^{-1} * X^t * y))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't want a character vector, but an expression, hence this

```
expression(R^2 == 0.85)
```

is what you need. In this case, you want to substitute in the result of another R operation. For that you want `substitute()` or `bquote()`. I find the latter easier to work with:

```
rsquarelm2 <- 0.855463
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "n")
text(5, 5, bquote(R^2 == .(round(rsquarelm2, 2))))
```

With `bquote()`, anything in `.( )` is evaluated and the result is included in the expression returned.

Comment: In my case, I need to start the line with `^1` - superscript number, which bquote seems to dislike. Would be interested in any suggestions (`expression(""^1") is not a solution, since I want to put the content of `text_in_var` and it seems the latter is not easy to do with `expression` - and easy with `bquote(.(text_in_var))`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The `paste` function returns a string, not an expression.  I prefer to use `bquote` for cases like this:

```
text(25, 200, bquote( R^2 == .(rs), list(rs=round(rsquarelm2,2))))
```

Answer (score 4):

How to include formatting and mathematical values in plots is [FAQ 7.13](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-substitute-into-a-plot-label_003f).

> For example, if `ahat` is an estimator of your parameter `a` of interest, use
>
> `title(substitute(hat(a) == ahat, list(ahat = ahat)))`
>
> (note that it is `‘==’` and not `‘=’`). Sometimes `bquote()` gives a more
>   compact form, e.g.,   `title(bquote(hat(a) = .(ahat)))`
>
> where subexpressions enclosed in `‘.()’` are replaced by their values.

`demo(plotmath)` is also useful.

---

In this case, you can use either

```
title(substitute(R^2 = rsq, list(rsq = format(rsquarelm2, digits = 2))))
```

or

```
title(bquote(R^2 == .(format(rsquarelm2, digits = 2))))
```

(`format` is more appropriate here than `round`, since you want to control how the value is displayed rather than creating an approximation of the value itself.)