# R How to get superscript in text with a bracket before the superscript

Tags: r

I know how to get superscripted text in a plot lable using parse or expression when I want to put X raised to the Y, e.g.

```
plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type='n',xlab=expression("example " (m^2)))
```

this works fine, as per these these pages

[How do I include a superscript to texts on a plot on R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965319/how-do-i-include-a-superscript-to-texts-on-a-plot-on-r)

[Superscript in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980761/superscript-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I want to have a lable that reads (^o C) where ^o is the raised degree symbol.   trying to delete the m part always gives me an error:

```
unexpected '^'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type='n',xlab=expression("example " (degree~C)))
```

[image]

or if no space is required between degree and C

```
plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type='n',xlab=expression("example " (degree*C)))
```

[image]

For details check

```
?plotmath
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type='n',xlab=expression("example " (paste(""^o, "C"))))
```

[image]